# Is CString::LoadString() thread-safe?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am implementing a multithreaded application that invokes modules from a legacy application written using MFC.

My code runs perfectly when I run it using only one thread, but if I run it using more than one thread, I always get an assertion when `CString::LoadString()` invokes `AfxGetResourceHandle()`. The string that is invoking `LoadString()` is a local string, so it is not being shared at all.

If I add a mutex before the `CString::LoadString()` everything goes ok, but because the size of the legacy app and the common use of this method, this solution would be hard to implement and would slow down the app.

I looked into the MS documentation and it says nothing about thread-safety or so on.

Do you know something about `LoadString()` and multithreaded environments? All the DLLs in my app have the same character set, they all are in DEBUG mode and they all use MFC shared DLL.

Comment: `LoadList()`? Do you mean `LoadString()`?

Comment: `The string that is invoking LoadList() is a local string, so it is not being shared at all`  Is the string a `CString`?  AFAIK, CString's are referenced counted, so in essence, they're shared.

Comment: What is the nature of the assertion?  FWIW, your issue seems very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505435/mfc-state-invalid-when-dll-called-through-loadlibrary

Comment: Sorry, it was LoadString, you were correct.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can only access MFC objects from threads created with CWinThread. You didn't provide the exact assertion you got on the secondary thread, but I'm guessing your 'other' threads are created some other way. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e(v=vs.100).aspx) for details on MFC vs. multithreading.

Comment: Actually I created my threads using the STL C++11 thread. By the way, how can I invoke the MFC stuff from threads created on .NET?